# Recipient address required Gmail API Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api

I'm trying to send out an email using the Gmail API, but I keep getting an error stating that I am not specifying a recipient to my email, even though I am inside of the email constant. I have tried using a hard-coded email address that I know exists, but it has not worked successfully. I am unsure as to why this is occuring. I will list both the API route in Node.js as well as the handleSubmit function that's calling the API route.

`sendGmail.js` API Route

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      const {
        alertType,
        alertLocationData,
        alertSubject,
        alertDetails,
        userEmail,
        distributionEmail,
        alertStartDate,
        alertEndDate,
        attachments,
      } = req.body;

      const locationNames = []
      const locationCodes = []
      const servicesAffected = []

      alertLocationData.forEach(item => {
        const location = item['Location Name']
        const code = item['Code']
        const services = item['Services']

        locationNames.push(location)
        locationCodes.push(code)
        servicesAffected.push(services)
      });

      const emailContent = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
        <EmailTemplate
          alertType={alertType}
          alertStartDate={alertStartDate}
          alertEndDate={alertEndDate}
          alertLocations={locationNames}
          alertLocationCodes={locationCodes}
          servicesAffected={servicesAffected}
          alertDetails={alertDetails}
        />
      )
      
      const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
      const token = await getToken({ req })

      if (!session || !token || !token.accessToken) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' })
      }

      const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2({})
      oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        access_token: token.accessToken,
        refresh_token: token.refreshToken,
      });

      const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oauth2Client })

      const sendEmail = async () => {
        try {
          const email = `
          From: <${userEmail}>
          To: <HARD-CODED EMAIL>
          Subject: ${alertSubject}
          Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

          ${emailContent}
        `;

          const base64EncodedEmail = Buffer.from(email).toString('base64')
          const response = await gmail.users.messages.send({
            userId: session.user.email,
            requestBody: {
              raw: base64EncodedEmail,
            },
          })

          console.log(`Email Sent: ${response.data}`)

          return res.status(200).json({ success: true })
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error sending email: ${error}`)
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to send email' })
        }
      };

      await sendEmail();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`An error has occurred: ${error}`);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' })
  }
};
```

Here is my `handleSubmit` function that is calling the API route:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      if (alertType == '' || alertLocationData == '' || alertSubject == '' || alertDetails == '' || userEmail == '' || distributionEmail == '') {
        setSnackbarOpen(true)
        handleOpenSnackbar('error', 'Please Fill Out All Form Fields')
      } else {
        setLoading(true)
        const payload = {
          alertType,
          alertLocationData,
          alertSubject,
          alertDetails,
          userEmail,
          distributionEmail,
          alertStartDate: alertStartDate.format(),
          alertEndDate: alertEndDate.format(),
          attachments,
          alertActive,
        }

        const res = await fetch('/api/alertHandling/postAlertData', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        })

        if (res.ok) {
          console.log('Data succesfully saved')
          
          const res2 = await fetch('/api/google/sendGmail', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload)
          })

          setLoading(false)
          if (dataFetchCallback) {
            dataFetchCallback
          }
          props.onClose()
          initValues()
        } else {
          setLoading(false)
          throw new Error(`Error: ${res.status}`)
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error submitting data: ${error}`)
    }
  }
```

As a note: I feel like this is not best practice, but right now it's just to get something to work appropriately, however any advice on how to improve the `handleSubmit` function is appreciated.

Comment: The spacing is absolutely critical.  You have a newline after the opening quote in your `const email`.  That newline is going to be part of the string, and an empty line terminates the headers.  In addition, all the intending space you have before the headers will ALSO be part of the message, and will screw up the parsing.  Those strings MUST start at column 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing is critical.  You need:

```
          const email = `From: <${userEmail}>
To: <HARD-CODED EMAIL>
Subject: ${alertSubject}
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

${emailContent}`;
```

Comment: This was correct and I was unaware of how significant spacing was in this situation. I have a new error of it not sending now because of invalid credentials, but that's a separate issue entirely. Regardless of that, thank you.